# Null object reference: When filling a textView with .txt data

Tags: java, android, xml

I need to `load` data from a `.txt file` by using the following method:

```
 public void getTextFromFile()
{
    File path = getExternalFilesDir(null);
    File file = new File(path, "alarmString.txt");

    int length = (int) file.length();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[length];

    FileInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream(file);

        in.read(bytes);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }finally {


        String contents = new String(bytes);
        TextView clockTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.clockText);
        assert clockTxt != null;
        clockTxt.setText(contents);
    }
}
```

When calling the method `getTextfromFile();`, under the `onCreate();` the program crashes, with giving me the following error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

I have tried to:

1. Check if the `id` is correct.
2. Made sure that the correct `layout` is being called by `setContentView(R.id.activity_main);`
3. Making sure that the method `getTextFromFile();` is being called under the `setContentView()`;

Thanks!

Comment: clockTxt is null, so R.id.clockText or GUI creation must be wrong.

Comment: make sure that your clockText is inside the right layout (the one created with the onCreate method). As said above, your TextView is not found, which makes it null.

Comment: Try to do the findview in the onCreate and pass the textview as an argument in the function `getTextFromFile(TextView tv)`.

Answer (score 1):

In a way or another your TextView isn't instantiated. 
To assert it you can still do something like:

```
if(clockTxt == null)
Log.d("TextView checking", "textview not found in layout");
```

Either the right layout isn't included, either the ID of your TextView is wrong.The assert isn't working here though.

Comment: I believe that I am calling from a different layout, since I have the `textview` in the  `fragment` and trying to create it from the main activity. After trying to call the textview from the fragment's class, the same error still persists. In addition I have done the following statement: `if(clockTxt == null) {
                Log.d("TextView checking", "textview not found in layout");
            }
            else
            {
                clockTxt.setText(contents);
            }` however, I am not having any output :( Thanks again

Comment: What do you obtain in logcat when you instantiate the textview in the fragment? I think that passing your String "contents" to your fragment to instantiate it there should work.